# generate a random range between two numbers

Tags: python, random, range

What is the pythonic (can use numpy) way to generate a random range of length `[range_length_min, range_length_max]` in the range `[range_start, range_end]`?

**Example:**

- range_length_min = 5
- range_length_max = 10
- range_start = 0
- range_end = 2000

Allowed Solutions:

- `[53, 59]`
- `[934, 941]`

Invalid Solutions:

- `[92, 94]` because length of range is less than `range_length_min`
- `[92, 104]` because length of the range is more than `range_length_max`
- `[-4, 3]` because start of range is less than `range_start`
- `[1998, 2004]` because end of range is less than `range_end`

**Current Solution:**

```
start = np.random.randint(range_start, range_end - (range_max_length - range_min_length))
end = start + np.random.randint(range_min_length, range_max_length)
```

This gives the correct result but does not sample uniformly. The `range_end - (range_max_length - range_min_length)` is a hack.

Comment: The problem seems to be underspecified. What distribution do you want on the intervals? If you want the intervals to be selected uniformly from the set of all valid intervals, there is a mathematical problem you need to solve prior to coding since the lengths of the intervals are not uniformly distributed over the range of possible lengths.

Comment: @JohnColeman I need to sample uniformly. The range lengths and the range locations must be sampled independently and uniformly.

Comment: "The range lengths and the range locations must be sampled independently and uniformly" doesn't make sense since the length and the location are not independent. The longer the interval, the more constraints there are on location. Furthermore, there will be more shorter subintervals than longer subintervals, so if you want to sample uniformly from the set of valid intervals, your selection *must* be biased in favor of shorter interevals

Comment: Ah, my bad. They aren't independent. Every range should be equally likely. My current solution for example leaves out the ranges at the edge which is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, based on weighting the choice of the length:

```
import random

def rand_interval(lmin,lmax,a,b):
    """picks random subinterval in [a,b] with length between lmin and lmax inclusive"""
    weights = [b-a - x + 1 for x in range(lmin,lmax+1)]
    length = random.choices(range(lmin,lmax+1),weights)[0]
    start = random.randint(a,b-length)
    return start, start + length
```

A test:

```
import collections
print(collections.Counter(rand_interval(1,2,1,3) for _ in range(10000)))
```

typical output:

```
Counter({(1, 2): 3389, (1, 3): 3386, (2, 3): 3225})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
from random import randint

a = randint(range_start, range_end - range_length_max)
b = randint(range_length_min, range_length_max)

r = [a, a+b]
```

Comment: With the configuration given in question, this solution cannot generate `[1994, 1999]`.

Comment: I think you could use [np.clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html), generate `a` in the entire range and then just clip `a+b` by `range_end`

Comment: That solution would favor ranges towards the end I think. The end will more likely to be `range_end` than other values.

Answer (score 0):

Just try making a function for specific needs:

```
>>> def foo(range_start, range_end, range_length_min, range_length_max):
...     v = random.randint(range_start, range_end)
...     v1 = random.randint(v + range_length_min, v + range_length_max if range_length_max <= range_end else range_end)
...     return [v, v1]
... 
>>> foo(range_start, range_end, range_length_min, range_length_max)
[1384, 1390]
```